# Converting String variable to array

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

I have created method that take certain data from an array, and creates a new dictionary with the array by adding in some pre-defined strings,

Im able to create the new array's I need, but I seem to be storing it as a String variable instead of as an array. Here is my Code:

```
var createContestantsDropdownlist = ContestantInfoDropdown();

function ContestantInfoDropdown() {
var ContestantTest = ['Contestant 1', 'Contestant 2', 'Contestant 3', 'Contestant 4'];  
var option = [];
    for (var i=0;i<ContestantTest.length;i++){
    option += '{value: \'' + ContestantTest[i] + '\'},';
    }
    option += '{value: \'Contestant 5\'}';
    return option
  };
```

When I take a look at the data that has been created, it's all in the correct format, but I need to try and remove the double quotes at the beginning and end to make it an array, and not a string value.
[See here how the string value Looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u6F7u.png).

All I would like to know is how to convert this from a string by simply removing the Double quotes at the beginning and the end, or am I completely on the wrong track here. any help appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: The double quotes are not part of the string. It's just the way the browser console shows you that it is a string.

Comment: If you want to make it an array, append objects to the string. You're *turning it into a string* by using `+=` with those strings you're building.

Comment: Well you're concatenating strings in your `option` variable, so it's a string.

Comment: using '+=' on 'options' variable cast it to a string. Instead use `option.push(ContestantTest[i])`

Comment: Are you looking for an array of objects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of concatenating a string you should push the values onto the array like:

```
function ContestantInfoDropdown() {
  var ContestantTest = ['Contestant 1', 'Contestant 2', 'Contestant 3', 'Contestant 4'];  
  var option = [];
      for (var i=0;i<ContestantTest.length;i++){
          option.push({value: ContestantTest[i] });
      }
      option.push({value: 'Contestant 5' });
      return option
};

var createContestantsDropdownlist = ContestantInfoDropdown();

console.log(createContestantsDropdownlist);
```

example fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/c9j1hure/

Comment: Thank you very much for your Help!! Worked straight away.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

`option.push({value: ContestantTest[i]});`

That will actually push the object onto the array rather than build out a string like you are now.

Answer (score 0):

using `+=` on `options` variable cast it to a `string`. Use `options.push(ContestantTest[i])` instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
var createContestantsDropdownlist = ContestantInfoDropdown

function ContestantInfoDropdown()
{
    var ContestantTest = ['Contestant 1', 'Contestant 2', 'Contestant 3', 'Contestant 4']
    var option = ContestantTest.map(function(x) { return { value: x } })
    option.push ({value: 'Contestant 5'})
    return option
}
```